# Can 若干 (Jakkan) be used as a substitute for 少し?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

As I understand it 若干 means 'some'. Can it be used the to substitute 少し when not talking about the specific quantity of more or less but using it as a vague descriptor like 'some'?

若干問題があった　vs　少し問題があった。

Comment: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/102360/meaning/m0u/ has the specific example you listed.

Answer (score 3):

- 若干 is more formal or literary than 少し.
- 少し is "a little" or "small amount", whereas 若干 is closer to "some" or "certain amount". 若干の問題 is usually a little more serious than 少しの問題, but they may be interchangeable depending on the context.
- Only 少し can mean "for a while". 少し話をする is okay but 若干話をする is not.

Comment: 「若干話をする」は僕の語感ではダメではないですが、確かに「少しの間」という意味にはならないですね（「多少のことについて」みたいな感じ）